# What is the sequence of files bash loads to set PATH variable

Tags: linux, macos, bash, path

I want to understand the way PATH variable is set in Linux/Mac. What all files are loaded and in what sequence to set the PATH variable for BASH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH can be a bit tricky, since your config files can do things like `PATH="~/bin:${PATH}"` or `PATH="${PATH}:~/bin"` and both are perfectly acceptable and have valid situational uses. I believe that what you're really asking is which config files the shell reads at startup -- determining how your PATH is assigned is a function of going through the config files in order and seeing what they do.

On OS X the following config files are read in this order:

For interactive login shells:
* `/etc/profile`
* First matched in order of: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`
* On shell termination: `~/.bash_logout`

For interactive non-login shells:
* `/private/etc/bashrc` (usually `/etc/bash.bashrc` in Linux)
* `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks devnall, this is helpful. Even I figured out that for me it loads /etc/bashrc and then ~/.bash+profile.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little on what devnall explained very well for interactive shells: WRT OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and perhaps earlier, `/etc/profile` will call `/usr/libexec/path_helper` if that file is available and executable.  `path_helper` will read each file in `/etc/paths.d/` and append the contents (which should be a single line each) to `$PATH` and then export the entire result.  This makes a clean, simple way of indicating why a particular path is set:

```
$ cat /etc/paths.d/40-XQuartz 
    /opt/X11/bin
$ cat /etc/paths.d/MacGPG2 
    /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

Then, if there is a `/etc/bashrc`, that will be called.

Then, one of .bash_profile, .bash_login, or .profile in your home directory is run.  (And, of course, `~/.bash_logout` upon exit.)